# Decode iOS base64 image

Tags: ios, base64, uiimagepickercontroller, decode, encode

I keep getting trouble decoding a encoded image.

I use the following code to encode my image returned from `UIImagePickerController`:

```
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData2 base64Encoding];
```

I tried resizing the image to 600x600, I also tried to compress the image.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [self imageWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];

    imgPreviewSelected.image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];

    CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
    CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
    int maxFileSize = 250*1024;

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);

    while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
    {
        compression -= 0.1;
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
    }

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    imagePickerReturnedImage = image;

    NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData2 base64Encoding];

    [utils postData:@"example.com" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image=%@", encodedString]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

When I try decoding the image that was sent to my database it tells me that the file is damaged.

I tried decoding it with PHP and the following website:
http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

My MYSQL database tells me that the image is 1MB, I think that is pretty large for an image of 600x600. Without compression it was 1,3MB.

I Use this method to scale my image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I hope anyone can help me out, thx

Answer (score 0):

I used another way without base64, so no answers required.

Comment: what method did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code look right.
Have you try copy your base64string to decode in that website?

you can check image size by

```
NSLog(@"dataSize: %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
```